# How do you type hint a function parameter that could be one of several types?

Tags: python, type-hinting

I'm adding type hints to some python 2 code and came across a minor dilemma. How does one hint the type of a function's return when that return could be one of several types?

I'm working with a function that looks like...

```
def foo(param):
    # do stuff
    return dict_
```

where `param` is a string and `dict_` is a dictionary with keys that are always strings and values that could be either integers or strings.

My solution was to type hint the function as shown below, but wanted to check that this was the proper strategy.

```
def foo(param):
    # type: (str) -> Dict[str, object]
    # do stuff
    return dict_
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a union (also called a sum type) `Union[str,int]` instead of the more general `object`:

```
def foo(param):
    # type: (str) -> Dict[str,Union[str,int]]
    # ...
    return dict_
```

Using `object`, you are stating that the values of the dictionary can be of any arbitrary type. `Union[str,int]` means it could be an `int`; or it could be a `str`; but it cannot be a `float`, or a `list`, or another `dict`, or anything other than an `int` or `str`.

Comment: I've never seen one-line comments used like that for type hinting.

Comment: It's the [suggested style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#suggested-syntax-for-python-2-7-and-straddling-code) for Python 2, which doesn't have function annotations.